# Calling SendAsynchronousRequest from Bakcground Thread

Tags: nsurlconnection

I am switching from the old API initWithRequest to the new iOS 5 API sendAsynchronousRequest. For the old one, the doc says the thread that sends the async request should also be responsible for handling the http response. To follow this rule I have to use the main thread to send the async request. Now with the new API, can I send async http request from whatever thread I want?